# Why index function in Perl is behaving strangely here

Tags: perl

Here is the sample code:

```
my $test = "Mike Xavier Smith/123-45-1111/student";
my $name = substr( $test, 0, index($test, "/") );
my $ssn = substr( $test,index($test,"/"));
my $type = substr( $test,index($test, "/", 2) );
print "$name, $ssn, $type \n";
exit;
```

Output:
Mike Xavier Smith, /123-45-1111/student, /123-45-1111/student

This line substr( $test,index($test, "/", 2) ); #offset should be from second occurrence of "/" which means it should print /student.
**But why it is printing from first occurrence of "/"?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not what the third argument of [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) is at all.

```
my $test = "Mike Xavier Smith/123-45-1111/student";

my $start = 0;
my $end   = index($test, "/", $start);
my $name  = substr($test, $start, $end);

$start  = $end+1;
$end    = index($test, "/", $start);
my $ssn = substr($test, $start, $end);

$start  = $end+1;
$end    = index($test, "/", $start);
my $type = substr($test, $start, $end);

print "$name, $ssn, $type\n";
```

Most people would just use `split`.

```
my $test = "Mike Xavier Smith/123-45-1111/student";
my ($name, $ssn, $type) = split(qr{/}, $test);
print "$name, $ssn, $type\n";
```

Comment: Then how come "perlmeme.org" shows 5 for index("perlmeme.org","e",2)?

Comment: @Jassi, Why wouldn't it? Remember, the positions are offsets (0-based).

Comment: Because "p" and "e" are omitted? Try `perl -we 'print index("perlmeme.org","e",3);'` - it would still get "5".